# How to measure time spent on disk I/O during a compile/link cycle?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction

On a Linux system, is there a way to measure the amount of time spent on disk I/O during a g++ compile/link cycle?

I am interested in measuring this metric before spending money on a SSD to improve build times.

Comment: Or use a RAM disk and see if there's a significant difference.

Comment: IME, the effect of SSD is huge.  For evidence, put on a build and listen to your current spinner.  A short length of wooden broom handle makes a good hard-disk stethoscope - the rattling of reading/writing lots of small files and directory entries will be impressive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ccache.

It is a cache for C/C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++.

It will improve a lot the compilation of already compiled sources. It means the most of time of compiler is spent executing code than waiting for IO(at least for C++).

If you need to clean your source frequently, it is a must have.

Compiling my project without ccache:
7 minutes and 46 seconds

with it:
24 seconds

Answer (score 0):

To amplify @MarkGarcia's comment:  It would be difficult to isolate wait time during i/o.  Linux does read ahead buffering from disk and does other optimizations which will frustrate getting a solid timing.

The effort to get an accurate i/o time is likely to affect the measurement anyway.  Maybe you could alter gcc to add instrumentation code, or put gcc inside an emulation box which times the i/o, or something else probably also quite heavy duty.

But what you really want to know is how is the overall compilation time affected by waiting for disk.

Simple method 1:  Run the compilation twice in a row and measure execution time—perhaps with the `times` command.  The first time will read the files from disk.  The second time will most probably use memory-cached copies of the files, unless a file is very large or the system is otherwise busy handling other memory intensive tasks (which would cause the file cache to clear soon).

Not as simple method 2:  Load all the needed files onto the ram disk—your build tree plus everything from `/usr/include` and the needed bits from `/usr/lib`— and alter the build to use those files instead.  This will be irritating to get right.